# Is it possible to locate subelements in protractor's .map?

Tags: protractor

Is it possible to locate sub-elements in protractor's .map?

I'm trying to modify example code from [here](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) to parse ToDo items into a data structure.

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    var todoStruct = todoList.map(function(el) {
      return {
        checkbox: el.element(by.model('todo.done')),
        label: el.element(by.tagName('span')).getText()
      };
    });

    todoStruct.then(function(resolvedTodoStruct) {
      expect(todoStruct.length).toEqual(3);
      expect(todoStruct[2].label).toEqual('write first protractor test');
    });
  });
});
```

From what I've read, map is the right choice for this kind of task. But for some reason, as soon as I use .element inside .map, protractor freezes. :(
Why would it happen? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Why do you need a `checkbox` reference inside the structure? Btw, if you replace `el.element(by.model('todo.done'))` with, for instance, `el.element(by.model('todo.done')).getText()` it would stop hanging.

Comment: I'd like to make a wrapper class to interact with a list of selectable items. In this class I would like to select elements by item names -- .select(...string) So I'll need to parse this control into a collection of label values (to compare against), and corresponding element references (to be able to click one if element matches).

Comment: At first I assumes,  that this is because .element() return reference to an element, but not promise. But even if I wrap it into promise

`var d = protractor.promise.defer();
d.fulfill(el.element(by.model('todo.done')));

return {
    checkbox: d.promise,
    label: el.element(by.tagName('span')).getText()
};`
it still fails.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce your problem. Here is a related "open" issue in protractor issue tracker: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2227.

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of work-arounds for this, though, while not pretty, seem work fine.

For the getText(), I moved the process of getting the text out of the JSON and then save the variable in the returned JSON.
For the element, the workaround is to wrap the element in a function:

```
var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
var spanText;
var todoStruct = todoList.map(function(el, index) {

    var spanText = el.element(by.tagName('span')).getText().then(function(t){
          return t;
      });

    return {
        checkbox: function(){
                    return todoList.get(this.index).element(by.model('todo.done'));
                  },
        label: spanText
        };

    });
```

Then when you want to access the element at a later time, you access as a function:
`todoStruct.checkbox().click();`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can get sub elements from a map in the following way

```js
  getRows() {
    return this.element.all(by.css('.ag-row')).map((row, index) => {
      return {
        index: index,
        title: row.element(by.css("[colid=\"title\"]")).getText(),
        operationStatus: row.element(by.css("[colid=\"operation_status_enum\"]")).getText()
      };
    });
  }

// You can print this in the following way

this.getRows().then((rows) => {
    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
      console.log(rows[i].title);
      console.log(rows[i].operationStatus);
    }
  });
```